# Multiple Conditions with in_array

Tags: php, arrays

I have situation where I am doing an **in_array** function

```
else if(in_array($status,$picked_status_code)) 
{

}
```

**Now along with in_array function , I want to do one more check with AND operators, so as to meet both the conditions**

Which would result like -

```
 else if(in_array($status,$picked_status_code) && (if $x >= $y)) 
    {
    Execution of Code
    }
```

This isn't working!

Answer (score 1):

You are already in an `else if` condition line,  remove that extra `if` statement

```
else if(in_array($status,$picked_status_code)  && $x >= $y) {

}
```

With a decent IDE like netbeans or php storm,  it should have thrown a syntax error there. Please download one of them.

Just a reminder. Don't forget that the syntax of `in_array()` is

```
in_array($needle,  $haystack,  true/false => strict checking);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
 else if(in_array($status,$picked_status_code) && $x >= $y) 
{
Execution of Code
}
```

You don't need the second if and the brackets are also unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your extra *if* within *else if*

```
 else if(in_array($status,$picked_status_code) && ($x >= $y)) 
    {
    Execution of Code
    }
```